# Python Tkinter, modify Text from outside the class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am trying to access the Text widget defined in class FirstPage from outside of the class.
I tried to solve this problem by creating a new instance of FirstPage, but could not find the right arguments to use. Also tried to use instance of GUI to gain the access, but unsuccessfully.

My problem is solved when I can use text.insert(0.0, t) from outside of the classes. It would help me modify the text displayed with Tkinter by functions that are not directly related with the GUI.

The origin of the code I am trying to use is found: [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

Also I removed lines that were not necessary for this question..

```
import Tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, '580x410')
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = FirstPage(container, self)
        self.frames[FirstPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        frame = self.frames[FirstPage]
        frame.tkraise()


class FirstPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        text = tk.Text(self , height=25, width=80)
        text.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nw")



app = GUI()
app.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the working code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, '580x410')
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = FirstPage(container, self)
        self.frames[FirstPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        frame = self.frames[FirstPage]
        frame.tkraise()

        page_name = FirstPage.__name__
        self.frames[page_name] = frame


    def get_page(self, page_name):
        return self.frames[page_name]


class FirstPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.text = tk.Text(self , height=25, width=80)
        self.text.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nw")



app = GUI()
app.get_page("FirstPage").text.insert("1.0", "Hello, world")
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do. As with any python object, you simply need a reference to the object in order to manipulate it.

The concept in the code you started with is to have a "controller" that controls access to all of the pages, since that object is where the pages are created. You can add a function in the controller that gives you a reference to a page, and then you can use that to call a function on that page.

Here's the changes you need to make to the controller:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        page_name = FirstPage.__name__
        self.frames[page_name] = frame
        ...

    def get_page(self, page_name):
        return self.frames[page_name]
```

You also need to modify `FirstPage` to keep a reference to the widget so that you can access it later:

```
class FirstPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.text = tk.Text(...)
        ...
```

From within any other code you can now access the text widget via `get_page` (but your pages must save a reference to the controller for this to work).

```
class AnotherPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.controller = controller
        ...

    def some_function(self):
        ...
        first_page = self.controller.get_page("FirstPage")
        text = first_page.text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        ...
        first_page.text.insert("end", "some new text\n")
```

Note that this technique works outside of any GUI pages. In your code, `app` is the controller, so you can do something like this:

```
app = GUI()
app.get_page("FirstPage").text.insert("1.0", "Hello, world")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Bryan! I was trying to ask a different question (I do not want to modify text by using different pages, but from other functions that are not related to GUI.) For example read in a .txt file and show the contents on FirstPage. I will edit my question to be more specific, but first will try to figure out the OOP theory in this code because am still very confused with it.

Comment: @additive: This answer still applies. You can do `app.get_page("FirstPage").text.insert(...)` from any other part of your code.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, you have been truly helpful! It works now.
Also just saying that def get_page(self, page_name) - self is missing and under def some_function needs to be self.text

Comment: @additive: I have fixed the missing self in get_page. Thank you for pointing it out