# update tkinter label text in page class python

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I need to automatically update a label based on text in a changing JSON file.  I read in several StackOverflow posts that `StringVar()` is a good built-in tk solution for linking label text to a variable.

My question differs from other posts in that I am attempting to update the label only from the `Page` class listed below (in just the code for this page).  In other words, `Page` is called somewhere in a larger app - and `Page` needs to load the label with the appropriate value from the JSON file.

Most other posts approach label updating from a separate method (i.e. a click event on the page).  However, I have several pages that load data from a json file that is constantly updating.

1. (**resolved**) When I run the code I get label text saying "PY_VAR1".  How do I fix this?
2. When `Page` is first accessed, the label text is correct (initialize did its work correctly).  However, when other app pages are accessed and then `Page` is returned to, the label text stays at the initialized value, not the updated json value.  How can the label value be updated after initialization *only* using `Page` code?

Note - [Python Tkinter, modify Text from outside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477338/python-tkinter-modify-text-from-outside-the-class) is similar to the issue, but I want to modify the text from *inside* the class.

**PY_VAR1 Update:**

PY_VAR1 issue fixed with `text = "Test Type: {}".format(data['test_type'])`.  However, still need solution for successful auto-updates of the label with json content changes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

# File system access library
import glob, os

import json

class Page(tk.Frame):
        test_type = tk.StringVar()

        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

                # app controller
                self.controller = controller

                test_type = tk.StringVar()

                # Read json file
                with open('data.json','r') as f:
                        data = json.load(f)

                test_type.set(data['test_type'])

                label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Test Type: " + str(test_type)))
                label.pack(pady=1,padx=1, side = "top", anchor = "n")

                button = ttk.Button(self, text="Previous Page",
                                    command=lambda: controller.show_page("Save_Test_Page"))
                button.pack(pady=1,padx=15, side = "left", expand = "no", anchor = "n")
```

Comment: your `test_type` is a instance of `tk.StringVar`. By `str()`ing it, you are just returning the assigned name for the `tk.StringVar`.

Comment: @abccd I used str() due when I encoutered a `TypeError: Can't convert 'StringVar' object to str implicitly` error

Comment: car't you just do `label = ttk.Label(self, text="Test Type: {}".format(data['test_type']))`?

Comment: @abccd OK, text in json file showing correctly now.  Question also asks how to update the label each time from in `Page`.  Any input on this?  Label does not auto-update yet.

Comment: Have you done any research? There are literally hundreds of questions and answers related to updating labels, and most tkinter documentation covers this as well.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, I have researched this in depth.  Most other posts approach label updating from a separate method (i.e. a click event on the page).  However, I have several pages that load data from a json file that is constantly updating.

When `Page` is first accessed, the label text is correct (initialize did its work correctly).  However, when other app pages are accessed and then `Page` is returned to, the label text stays at the initialized value, not the updated json value.  The question is - how can the label value be updated after initialization _only_ using `Page` code?

Comment: [Python Tkinter, modify Text from outside the class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477338/python-tkinter-modify-text-from-outside-the-class) is essentially similar to the issue, but I want to modify the text from _inside_ the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

# File system access library
import glob, os

import json

class Page(tk.Frame):
        test_type = tk.StringVar()

        def update_lable(self, label):
                # Read json file
                with open('data.json','r') as f:
                        data = json.load(f)
                label['text'] = "Test Type: {}".format(data['test_type'])
                #rerun this every 1000 ms or 1 second
                root.after(1000, self.update_lable(label)) #or whatever your root was called


        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

                # app controller
                self.controller = controller


                # Read json file
                with open('data.json','r') as f:
                        data = json.load(f)


                label = ttk.Label(self, text="Test Type: {}".format(data['test_type']))
                label.pack(pady=1,padx=1, side = "top", anchor = "n")
                self.update_label(label)
                button = ttk.Button(self, text="Previous Page",
                                    command=lambda: controller.show_page("Save_Test_Page"))
                button.pack(pady=1,padx=15, side = "left", expand = "no", anchor = "n")
```

Comment: `after` is exactly the function I need.  Thanks!  This has been bugging me for a long time...